# How to import .json connections file into VSO Orace database developer tools?

Tags: database, oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle-sqldeveloper, developer-tools

How do we import connections into Visual studio oracle database developer tools.
I have .json export file from SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

That json file is built for importing connections into SQL Developer only, not other database tools.

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Code Oracle Extension you can not import sql connection json file.
you have to add connection one by one.